# C++ reference return of class object-why copy constructor not called?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code dealing with reference return:

```
class Test  
{  
    public:  
    int data;

    Test() { data = 0; }
    Test(int u) { data = u;}

    Test& myfunction ();// function returning reference
    Test(Test& b) // copy constructor
    {
    cout<<"consructor called";
    }

    void print() { cout << data<<endl; }
};  
Test m(97);
Test& Test:: myfunction ()
{
    return m;
};    

int main()
{   Test a;
    Test b;
    b=a.myfunction();// why copy constructor not called?

    b.print();
    m.data=5;
    b.print();// if b is a reference of m then why its value not changed?

    return 0;
}
```

i hav two problem
1) is **'b' becomes reference of 'm'** through following:

```
    b=a.myfunction();
```

if so then why its value not changed when value of 'm' is changed in

```
m.data=5;
```

2) **is b a normal object?**. if so then why copy constructor is not called when following code is executed

```
b=a.myfunction();
```

the above code compiles fine with the following output:
97
5

Comment: `b` is not a reference. The return type being a reference doesn't change that fact.

Comment: 1) As chris said, `b` is not a reference 2) The copy assignment operator of `Test` is called on `b` (its not the same as  the copy constructor)

Comment: @chris if 'b' is not a reference to 'm' and thus a normal object then why copy constructor is not being called?

Comment: @user3249833:  Because `b` was already constructed.  See my answer.

Comment: @john Dibling 
is there any way through which i can return a reference through Myfunction and assign it to 'b'?

Comment: @user3249833 The problem is not on your function but in the declaration of your variable. You should declare a reference to Test.

Test a;
Test& b = a.myfunction();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Test b;
```

You just constructed the `b` object, using `Test`'s default constructor.  Nothing you do will somehow magically "reconstruct" `b`.  Everything you do with `b` now is being done on an already-constructed `b`.

```
b=a.myfunction();// why copy constructor not called?
```

The copy constructor isn't called because *nothing is being constructed*.  Since you're assigning something to an already-constructed object, the object's copy assignment operator (`operator=`) is called.

Now if you *want* to ensure the copy constructor is called, you should do this instead:

```
Test b = a.myfunction();
```

---

> is 'b' becomes reference of 'm'

No.  You already declared `b` to be a `Test` object.  Once an object is declared, nothing you do will change it's type.  Objects don't change types once created.

Since `myfunction()` returns a reference, `b`'s assignment operator uses that as the right-hand-side.  It doesn't make `b` a reference -- it just copies stuff from the thing returned by `myfunction()`, which just so happens to be a reference to something else.

> is b a normal object?

Yes.  Well, if I'm honest, I don't know what you mean exactly by "normal object."  But in whatever sense you mean it, the answer is sureley yes.  It's not a reference, and there's nothing magic about `b` (or anything else in C++, though it may seem so.)

Comment: why the following code does not work

 `Test Test:: myfunction ()
    {
        return m;
    };`
i want to return a Test object

Answer (score 0):

Object b has already been constructed in the line above, so it will not call copy constructor but the assignment operator.

```
// Using copy constructor:
Test a;
Test b = a.myfunction();

// Using assignment operator
Test c;
c = a.myfunction();
```

Comment: why the following code does not work

 `Test Test:: myfunction ()
    {
        return m;
    };`
i want to return a Test object

Comment: @user3249833 Be more specific. What did you expected it to do?

Comment: actually i want to return a reference through 'Myfunction' and assign it to 'b'..( so as a result b becomes a reference to m) 
is there any way..?